# Basics about the partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Does the following equation correct?

$$\frac{f(x+dx,y)-f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$

Is mixing $dx$ with $\partial x$ in one single equation common in math?

---

Sorry I learnt calculus a few years ago and forgot them all.

Comment: If you're allowing yourself to use infinitesimals, then it seems to me that the statement $\frac{f(x + \partial x,y) - f(x,y)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ would be acceptable.  Here $\partial x$ is an infinitesimal change in the value of $x$, and $\partial f$ is the corresponding infinitesimal change in the value of $f$.  However, if you object to the use of infinitesimals then you would need to make a statement involving limits as @G.Sassatelli suggested.

Comment: Actually, the derivative is a limit. So, you should present that as a limit. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative . Also, the notation is wrong and is not used.

Comment: I don't know, is it the same as the derivative of x^2?

Comment: Okay, let's see, let's see, we've got to come up with a definition of partial derivative with respect to a whole bunch of variables, so let me think, let me think...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even a statement such as $\frac{g(x+dx)-g(x)}{dx}=g'(x)$ for a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is hardly ever "correct" (one could in principle make any statement "correct" by appropriately defining his very own special notation, but that does not prevent others from grumbling about it). The correct notation for your case is $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$$

Comment: So I could write: $$\lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{f(x+dx,y)-f(x,y)}{dx}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$$ or $$\lim_{\partial x\to 0}\lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{f(x+dx,y)-f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$$?

Comment: Th second one is definitely wrong. The first one is right, provided you are using a very bad notation.

Comment: What if I change the second one to $$\lim_{g\to 0}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{g}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$$ ?

Comment: Just like in the previous version, that quantity is $0$ whenever the function $t\mapsto f(t,y)$ is continuous at $x$, and undefined otherwise.